# Create if data doesn't exist with Symfony 4

Tags: doctrine, symfony4

I have a form that the user filled with a name. Based on that name, I do an AJAX request on my database to know if someone exists with that name. If it exists I show the full form with inputs filled with data from the database. Otherwise I show an empty full form. 
At the submission, if the data were already in the database I want to update them but if not I need to insert those data. Inserting new data is working fine.

Here is my controller function that is linked to the form submission :

```
    /**
     *@Route("adherent/new", name="adherent_new")
     */
    public function new(Request $request)
    {
        $adherent = new Adherent();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $form = $this->createForm(AdherentType::class, $adherent);    
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $produitRepository = $em->getRepository(Produit::class);
        $allProduit = $produitRepository->findAll();

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            $id = $request->request->get('id');
            //if id exists then update
            //otherwise create a new entry

            $adherent = $form->getData();
            $em->persist($adherent);
            $em -> flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('adherent_accueil');
        }


        return $this->render('adherent/new.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'produits' => $allProduit
        ]);

    }
```

Is there a way to handle this with Symfony ? Or do I have to do this manually ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I see what you mean. I didn't have a id property in adherent class because it extends a superclass abstract class Demandeur which has the id. So in my adherentType form I didn't put the id property in it, but I added it in the html template directly. That explains why I try to fetch it with

```
$id = $request->request->get('id');
```

Because I've tried to use getData() and since my entity Adherent doesn't have the id property and so forth the setId() method, I got an exception :

```
Could not determine access type for property "id" in class "App\Entity\Adherent": Neither the property "id" nor one of the methods "addId()"/"removeId()", "setId()", "id()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "App\Entity\Adherent".
```

which is true. Before that, I tried the add function and everything was working fine, ids and relations.

```
class AdherentType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     *{@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {     
        $builder 
            ->add('id', IntegerType::class)
            ->add('nom', TextType::class, [
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank(),
                    new Length(['max'=>50]),
                ]
            ])
            ->add('prenom', TextType::class, [
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank(),
                    new Length(['max'=>50]),
                ]
            ])
            ->add('numSocietaire', IntegerType::class, [
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank(),
                    new Length(['max'=>30]),
                ]
            ])
            ->add('anciennete', IntegerType::class, [
                'required' => 'false',
            ])
            ->add('contratActif', IntegerType::class, [
                'required' => 'false',
            ])
            ->add('dateNaiss', DateType::class, [
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'required' => 'false',
            ])
            ->add('dateAdhes', DateType::class,[
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'required' => 'false',
                'empty_data' => '',
            ])
            ->add('datePremMut', DateType::class, [
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'required' => 'false',
            ])
            ->add('nbBenef', IntegerType::class, [
                'required' => 'false',
            ])
            ->add('nbIncidPaimt', IntegerType::class, [
                'required' => 'false',   
            ])
            ->add('detailContrat', DetailContratType::class)
            ->add('formule', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Formule::class,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->orderBy('u.libelle', 'ASC');
                },
                'choice_label' => 'libelle',
                'required' => 'false',
            ])
            ->add('ancienneFormule', TextType::class, [
                'required' => 'false',
            ])
            ->add('resiliation', ResiliationType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Créer l\'adhérent']);


    }
```

I just tried to add a Demandeur (super class) form with id property in my adherent form but it is an inheritance between Adherent and Demandeur not a relation.

```
class DemandeurType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     *{@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {     
        $builder 
            ->add('id', IntegerType::class);
    }
}

class AdherentType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     *{@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {     
        $builder 
            ->add('demandeur', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Demandeur::class
            ])
            ....
    }
}
```

There is something I don't understand for it is not working the way I think it should ...

EDIT : 
I have add the

```
parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
```

in my adherenttype class, I don't have any errors anymore but still doesn't want to update anything, just adding...

EDIT : I managed to get this working ! So I put my solution in case it interested somebody some day ! 
I create a UpdateDemandeur.php file in the EventListener folder. I put in it the function preUpdate but epty because nothing needed to be done on the Demandeur table before update. 
The tricky part was in my controller. Because I didn't send any objet to my forms, when the forms were submitted the objet I got was new to Symfony event if I use the setId($id) function because of the entity manager. I had to use the merge function. Here is te code I'm using and it is working.

```
        if($request->isMethod('POST')){
            foreach($forms as $form){
                $form->handleRequest($request);
                if( !$form->isSubmitted()) continue;

                if($form->isValid()){
                    $demandeur = $form->getData();
                    $id = $request->request->get($type)['id'];
                    if($id > 0) {
                        $demandeur->setId($id);
                        //Need to merge the new demandeur Object filled 
                        //with data from the form to update it in database
                        $dem = $em->merge($demandeur);

                    } else {
                        $em->persist($demandeur);
                    }
                    $em->flush();
                    return $this->redirectToRoute('demandeur_add');
                }
            }
        }
```

Hope it will help someone !